# Simple PHP date question

Tags: php

I have the following string:

```
$date = 2011-08-29 14:53:15;
```

when I do this:

```
echo date('F j, Y', $date);
```

I get December 31, 1969 instead of August 29, 2011. How to get the right date?

Comment: `date()` requires a timestamp (seconds since the epoch). You're passing in a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) on your `$date` value.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo date('f j, Y',strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
   $date = strtotime($date);
   echo date('F j, Y', $date);
?>
```

To explain...

The function `date()` is expecting a unix time-stamp (something like 23498034).  the function `strtotime()` takes a normal looking date that a person would make, and converts it to a timestamp.  Then you're good to go.